# Polygon Trace in Layout

Tags: arcgis-pro, graphics, trace

I am trying to add a graphic polygon to a 3D map layout. Now, I would like to trace the polygon along a layer, how can I do this?

When I hover the cursor along the border of the layer, I don't see any auto trace, maybe I need to press and hold a keyboard key or something.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking to do, tracing along an existing geometry is not a capability of a graphic, which are nothing more than "dumb shapes" drawn onto a map or a layout. Tracing along an existing edge is a capability of the construction tools for creating features.  If you want to topologically align to edges you need to be capturing features into an existing or new layer.